# If не срабатывает

Tags: javascript

Пытаюсь сравнить значения введенные в форму со значениями заданными вручную и редиректнуть на другую страницу если совпадут, но почему то не получаются(Значения из формы получаю верные, потому что alert() выводит то что нужно, а вот редиректа не происходит), Где ошибка в if?

```
var usrname = 0;
var pswrd = 0;

function authentication() {
  usrname = document.getElementById("username").value;
  pswrd = document.getElementById("password").value;

  console.log(usrname, pswrd);

  if (usrname == "username" && pswrd == "12345678") {
    window.location = "http://google.com";
  } else {
    alert("Вы не зарегистрированы как должник, либо неправильно введен логин и / или пароль.")
  }
}
```

**ОБНОВЛЕНИЕ**  Выложил html по просьбам.

```
<form id="login">
    <h1>Форма входа</h1>
    <fieldset id="inputs">
        <input id="username" type="text" placeholder="Логин" autofocus 
required>
        <input id="password" type="text" placeholder="Пароль" required>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset id="actions">
        <input type="submit" id="submit" value="ВОЙТИ" 
onclick="authentication()">
        <a href="">Забыли пароль?</a>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

*тот html с которым не работает window.location*

Comment: статус: не воспроизводится ...... https://jsfiddle.net/uqrxhq8a/

Comment: То есть window.location не работает внутри if?

Comment: Потому что если ввожу неправильный логин/пароль он выдаает что не зарегистрирован

Comment: Что выводит `alert ( usrname + pswrd );` ?. При вашем расклад должно выводить `username12345678`.

Comment: `window.location.href = "http://google.com";`

Comment: @AVM именно это и выводит, знаю что пробела нет это просто для проверки того что значения присвоились

Comment: @br3t уже пробовал и window.location.href и еще что-то, ничего из трех не срабатывает

Comment: Как То сразу нe заметил,@br3t дал правильный ответ.

Comment: Тут работает код https://codepen.io/anon/pen/EmOEYV , редиректит на главную?

Comment: @br3t с алертом все прекрасно, проблема именно в том что не работает редирект, нет, не на главную, в будушем нужно будет на разные страницы сайта, предлагаете локальный путь?

Comment: На кодпэне у вас в нижней части произошел редирект на главную codepen.io?

Comment: `проблема именно в том что не работает редирект `? .Поясните ,ваш блок `if`  срабатывает ? и как понять не работает,ошибку выдаёт или что,как вы определяете что не работает,просто неполучив ожидаемый результат делаете вывод ?

Comment: Не может быть чтоб попав в блок  `if` не сработал `window.location.href = "https://google.com";`

Comment: @AVM  Сам блок if срабатывает если там например alert(); а с редиректом не работает, так же если не совпадают логин/пароль прекрасно срабатывает else

Comment: Пруф где? Видео записывай с открытой консолью.

Comment: поддерживаю идею с видео)

Comment: @Lspewz Когда, где вызывается функция `authentication`?

Comment: @Igor скорее всего так `<form onsubmit="authentication()">`

Comment: выложи `html` код

Comment: @АлексейШиманский - тогда ответ от Qwertiy может сработать

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В обработчике события `submit` формы сделай `event.preventDefault()`.

Answer (score 1):

Если в коде написано также, как и сейчас, то ошибка заключается вот в этой строке:

```
 alert("Вы не зарегистрированы как должник, либо неправильно введен 
логин и/или пароль.")
```

Потому что нельзя так в коде писать текст на разных строках без конкатенации. Должно быть либо в одну строку

```
alert("Вы не зарегистрированы как должник, либо неправильно введен логин и/или пароль.");
```

либо конкатенировать

```
alert("Вы не зарегистрированы как должник, либо неправильно введен " +
    + "логин и/или пароль.")
```

либо для *ES6* использовать [Шаблонные строки](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/template_strings), которые поддерживают это. Но в IE и Safari данная новинка не будет работать, т.к. нет совместимости с ними.

И при синтаксических ошибках **ВСЕГДА** пишутся сообщения в консоли. Она вообще у вас должна быть всегда открыта.

Comment: либо используйте обратные кавычки \``Вы не зарегистрированы как должник, либо неправильно введен логин и/или пароль.\``

Comment: В коде все в одну строку, синтаксических ошибок консоль не выдает

Comment: @Lspewz значит  [статус: не воспроизводится](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/668725/if-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D1%81%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82/668728#comment970244_668725)

Comment: @АлексейШиманский  Если написано не в if работает прекрасно